# How to avoid onitemclick when scrolling a gridview

Tags: android

I'm using a gridview in my application, I have implemented dispatchTouchEvent to avoid scrolling of the gridview.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

but when I scrolling the gridview, it sometimes get an event in onItemClick. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: are you using a adapter in gridview?

Comment: check my answer below ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onScrollListener()` on `GridView`, and in the `onScrollStateChanged()` method you can manage a `boolean` to check if the view is scrolling, code would be something like this,

declare a `boolean` at class level with a value `false`

```
boolean isScrolling = false;
```

then use the `onScrollListener` with `GridView`, for e.g something like :

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(scrollState == 
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                isScrolling = true;
            } else if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                isScrolling = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and then in your `onItemClick()` check for `isScrolling` to allow click or not,

Comment: thanks for your help.but in fact,i have implemented dispatchTouchEvent to avoid scrolling of the gridview,so  the gridview can not scroll,my expected behavior is that when ever I try to scroll in the GridView, that event should be ignored. but, I get an event in onItemClick even after returning true in dispatchTouchEvent , Is there a way to avoid onItemClick in case of scroll on GridView?

Comment: did you try the above ?

Comment: yes,onScrollStateChanged is never called,isScrolling is always false

Answer (score 0):

Set on adapter's Parent layout this attribute :

```
android:focusable="false"
```